# TypeError: 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
import random

noun = ["fossil" , "horse" , "aardvark" , "chef" , "judge"]
verb= [ "kicks", "jingles", "bounces", "slurps", "meows"]
adjs= ["fury" , "balding" , "incredulous" , "fragant"]
prep= ["against" , "after" , "into" , "beneath" , "for", "in"]
ads= ["curiously" , "extravagantly" , "furiously" , "sensuously"]
 
def selectn(list, n) :
    selection = []
    while (len(selection) != n) : 
        w = random.choice(list)
        if w not in selection :
            selection.append(w)
    print(selection)

def makePoem() :
    my_nouns = selectn(noun,3)
    my_verbs = selectn(verb,3)
    my_adj = selectn(adjs,3)
    my_adverb = selectn(ads,1)
    my_prepo = selectn(prep,2)
    
    print ("A {} {}".format(my_adj[0], my_nouns[0]))
    print("")
    print("A {} {} {} {} the {} {}".format(my_adj[0], my_nouns[0], my_verbs[0], my_prepo[0], my_adj[1], my_nouns[1]))
    print("{}, the {} {}".format(my_adverb[0], my_nouns[0], my_verbs[1]))
    print("the {} {} {} a {} {}".format(my_nouns[1], my_verbs[2], my_prepo[1], my_adj[2], my_nouns[2]))

makePoem()
```

I'm getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` when I call `makePoem`. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Is `selectn()` supposed to return something?

Comment: `selectn()` returns the string `selection`.

Comment: When you post why-does-my-code-not-work-questions you should: 1) tell what behaviour you get and what behaviour you expected, 2) make sure your example has the behaviour you claim. The posted code is not formatted properly so it will not have the behaviour you claim. In addition the **exact** error message is often helpful because in python it often tells where the error is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @skyking I will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning `selection`, you're printing it instead. Replace `print(selection)` with `return selection`.